Css Resizable Headers not working with overflow of parent div
I am trying to make an HTML table with resizable headers using CSS resize. I want to resize the header and the table overflow with a scroll. I am using a setup like this, but I can't get it to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code with pictures.
.scroll {
    width: 800px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    position: relative;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

th, td {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

th {
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: left;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: hidden;
}

what i am trying to achieve
I think the problem is with the table acting like a flex div taking the max width of the parent.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044479/table-with-sticky-header-and-resizable-columns-without-using-jquery

for anyone in the future with this problem here is the solution.


.scroll {
    width: 800px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 150px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

th, td {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #424242;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    min-width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
}

th {
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    position: relative;
}

th {
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: horizontal;
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
        <div class="scroll">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>a</th>
                        <th>b</th>
                        <th>c</th>
                        <th>d</th>
                        <th>f</th>
                        <th>g</th>
                        <th>h</th>
                        <th>i</th>
                        <th>j</th>
                        <th>k</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>



