# How to freeze the table headers without any plugins and show when scrolled vertically?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used many plugins like freezeHeaders, stickytableHeaders, floatThead , nothing helped me.

In my project the header and footer are constant .It comes dynamic.Its a huge project. In my current jsp , i'll show the title and table which contains headers and dynamic data.

I need to have a freeze headers between the header and footer.

Can anyone give an exact idea to solve this problem.

Please.

Comment: Have fix height for tbody with overflow auto.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freezing/Fixing the Top Header Row of a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307135/freezing-fixing-the-top-header-row-of-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example below:

```css
.fixed_headers {
  width: 750px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.fixed_headers th {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.fixed_headers th,
.fixed_headers td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(1),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(2),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(3),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 350px;
}
.fixed_headers thead {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FDFDFD;
}
.fixed_headers thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.fixed_headers tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.fixed_headers tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.old_ie_wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 750px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.old_ie_wrapper tbody {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<table class="fixed_headers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pear</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grape</td>
      <td>Purple / Green</td>
      <td>These are purple and green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>Yellow</td>
      <td>These are yellow.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kiwi</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Plum</td>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>These are Purple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Watermelon</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tomato</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cantelope</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange inside.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Honeydew</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green inside.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Papaya</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Raspberry</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>These are blue.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mango</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Passion Fruit</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```