# HTML table data is shifting in another columns

Tags: html

While solving fixed header issue Table data is mis-aligning(displaying) in another columns. The header is now fixed.

Any inputs to solve mis-align of data in another columns?

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table border="1" style="width: 600px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
      <td>Column 5</td>
      <td>Column 6</td>
      <td>Column 7</td>
      <td>Column 8</td>
      <td>Column 9</td>
      <td>Column 10</td>
      <td>Column 11</td>
      <td>Column 12</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div style="overflow: auto;height: 100px; width: 620px;">
    <table border="1" style="width: 600px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>Value 1 Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 3</td>
        <td>Value 4 Value 4</td>
        <td>Value 5</td>
        <td>Value 6</td>
        <td>Value 7</td>
        <td>Value 8</td>
        <td>Value 9</td>
        <td>Value 10</td>
        <td>Value 11</td>
        <td>Value 12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value 1 Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 3</td>
        <td>Value 4</td>
        <td>Value 5 Value 5</td>
        <td>Value 6</td>
        <td>Value 7</td>
        <td>Value 8</td>
        <td>Value 9</td>
        <td>Value 10</td>
        <td>Value 11</td>
        <td>Value 12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value 1 Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 3</td>
        <td>Value 4 Value 4</td>
        <td>Value 5</td>
        <td>Value 6</td>
        <td>Value 7 Value 7</td>
        <td>Value 8</td>
        <td>Value 9</td>
        <td>Value 10</td>
        <td>Value 11</td>
        <td>Value 12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Value 1 Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 3</td>
        <td>Value 4 Value 4</td>
        <td>Value 5</td>
        <td>Value 6</td>
        <td>Value 7</td>
        <td>Value 8</td>
        <td>Value 9</td>
        <td>Value 10</td>
        <td>Value 11</td>
        <td>Value 12</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Freeze the top row for an html table only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423768/freeze-the-top-row-for-an-html-table-only)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a separate table for the values? You can have them in the same table.

Comment: Hi Anjan For solving fixed header issue I used seperate table for values.

Comment: These links might help:

http://rcswebsolutions.wordpress.com/2007/01/02/scrolling-html-table-with-fixed-header/

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

http://blog.oxagile.com/2009/10/26/scrollable-html-table-with-fixed-header-for-ie-7-ie-8-firefox-35-chrome/

Comment: is there any alternative ways is there

Comment: This example solved my issue http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1031/Fixed-Headers-Scrolling-Tables-With-jQuery