# Having issues styling a table

Tags: html, css

I have been digging around on the internet at other SOF questions and other various websites. I seem to be having issues getting the scrollbars/alignment of this table to work nicely.

I have a table of the following format:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 is slightly longer                                              | Column 3 | Column ......
Data     | some random text is in here and should make the column 2 expand this far | data     | .....
Data     | some random text is in here and should make the column 2 expand this far | data     | .....
Data     | some random text is in here and should make the column 2 expand this far | data     | .....
Data     | some random text is in here and should make the column 2 expand this far | data     | .....
Data     | some random text is in here and should make the column 2 expand this far | data     | .....
Data     | some random text is in here and should make the column 2 expand this far | data     | .....
Data     | some random text is in here and should make the column 2 expand this far | data     | .....
Data     | some random text is in here and should make the column 2 expand this far | data     | .....
Data     | some random text is in here and should make the column 2 expand this far | data     | .....
Data     | some random text is in here and should make the column 2 expand this far | data     | .....
Data     | At this row I want it to not be showing and you have 2 scroll down 2 see | data     | .....
Data     | At this row I want it to not be showing and you have 2 scroll down 2 see | data     | .....
```

The challenging part I am having is I cannot seem to get the `<thead><tr>` part at the top (Column 1, Column 2) to continue to show as visible while scrolling down vertically. I also need to be able to scroll horziontally like in the code samplet that SOF displays shows up above and keep the `<thead>` and the `<tbody>` parts aligned.

Anyone have a jsfiddle or something similar handy that shows a proper example of this?

Thanks.

Comment: You posted your table, but not your code. We can't _really_ tell what you're doing without the actual html.

Comment: if you want to freeze the top row of your table there are many questions along those lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423768/freeze-the-top-row-for-an-html-table-only-fixed-table-header-scrolling

Comment: The truth is I have no idea what I'm doing, i know how to make basic HTML but I am not very good when it comes to CSS.