# Fixed header scrolling table with multiple tbody elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble achieving a fixed header scroll-able table which contains multiple tbody elements.

Basically, I'd like to put a table inside a container element of fixed size. I'd then like to scroll through any overflowing table elements, without the headers moving.

The table needs to be styled with twitter-bootstrap, but I'm not sure that's relevant to the question

Hope that makes sense!

Here is a fiddle (obviously not quite working as intended yet)
https://jsfiddle.net/whbbwv7g/

And the code:

```
<div id="tableContainer">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Head 1</th>
                <th>Head 2</th>
                <th>Head 3</th>
                <th>Head 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


            <tbody>            
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>                
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>            
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>                
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>            
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>                
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>


    </table> 
</div>
```

The only css is:

```
#tableContainer {
    width: 300px;
    height:150px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stacking two tables on top of eachother in a div, and only using the TH elements in the top table - fix its position, and set the overflow to scroll on the bottom table.
`<div>`
`<table class="toptable">`
`<!--put table headers here-->`
`</table>`
`<table class="toptable">`
`<!--put table headers here-->`
`</table>`
`<table class="bottomtable">`
`<!--put table rows here and set this table to overflow:scroll;-->`
`</table>`
`</div>`

Answer (score 1):

You can divide your headers and body into separate tables. The top level table will only have the headers as you can assign the scrollable properties for the content table.

A working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/psk11/mjxb6vcr/

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table

<table style="height:300px;display:block;overflow-y:auto;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Row 1 Col 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Row 1 Col 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Row 1 Col 3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Row 2 Col 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Row 2 Col 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Row 2 Col 3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>


</table>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution because the columns in the two tables will not size together as they would in a normal table.

Comment: Somehow we need to fix the widths of all cells to come up with a fixed header with scrollable rows.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved elsewhere:

[Freeze the top row for an html table only (Fixed Table Header Scrolling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423768/freeze-the-top-row-for-an-html-table-only-fixed-table-header-scrolling)

In brief, the solution is to use `position: sticky` on the `th` - this is what I use:

```css
table thead th {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Here's a link to caveats and support for `sticky`:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky