# Fix table head while scrolling tbody and thead column aligned to tbody column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is table with fixed outer height, and i need when scroll start, thead will be fixed and tbody will be scroll that show heading of each column.Is there any idea to fix heading of table on top and inner content of table will be scroll.

```css
.max_height{max-height:100px;overflow:auto;}
```

```html
<div class="max_height">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>  <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>     
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freeze the top row for an html table only (Fixed Table Header Scrolling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423768/freeze-the-top-row-for-an-html-table-only-fixed-table-header-scrolling)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque

Comment: Be aware: the 2 suggested duplicates have quite old accepted answers.  There are updated answers that work within those questions, using just css, so worth scrolling down.  In 2019, there's no need to be using a javascript solution for this (as per both accepted answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this with updated css

```css
.max_height{margin:0px;max-width:450px;}
table thead,table tbody{
  display:block;
}

table tbody{
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}

table tr{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="max_height">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>  <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>     
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```