# fixing Header of table and making table body scrollale

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table

I am working in Angular Project but stuck in a **design Issue**

I am want to **scroll the body of the table** making body **header fixed**

I tried to do the at but not able to scroll just table body

My code and design is ready I have put it in below link -

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x8c89j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Freeze the top row for an html table only (Fixed Table Header Scrolling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423768/freeze-the-top-row-for-an-html-table-only-fixed-table-header-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

Please update your table style as below

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

thead {
  display: table; 
  width: calc(100% - 17px); 
}

tbody {
  display: block; 
  max-height: 200px; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  word-break: break-all; 
}

tr {
  display: table; 
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
}

tr th:first-child,
tr td:first-child {
  width: 100px;
}
```