# Errors with freeze table header - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, display

I am trying to enter entries in table inputs for my inventory website. I want to freeze the headers of each column and tried doing it with this -> [Freeze the top row for an html table only (Fixed Table Header Scrolling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423768/freeze-the-top-row-for-an-html-table-only-fixed-table-header-scrolling)

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var to_show = '';
  for(var i = 1 ; i < 50 ; i++){
    to_show += '<tr><td><input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="product_name_'+ i +'" name="product_name_'+i+'" onkeyup="productSearch(this.value, '+i+')" tabindex="-1" style="font-size:larger;"></td>';
    to_show += '<td><input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="location_'+ i +'" name="location_'+ i +'" onkeyup="productSearch(this.value, '+ i +')" tabindex="-1" style="font-size:larger;"></td></tr>';
  }
  document.getElementById('addInside_tr_20').innerHTML = to_show;
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400|Oswald:200,300,400&display=swap");
:root {
  --purple-theme: #091428;
  --lightpurple-theme: #0f3a41;
  --gray-bg-heading: #b8b8b8;
  --gray-bg-sidebar: #dee3e7;
  --lightgreen-theme: #65ffce;
  --green-theme: #46b692;
  --red-theme: #f75b54;
}
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  background: var(--lightpurple-theme);
}
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: var(--green-theme);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: var(--lightgreen-theme);
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
::-moz-selection {
  /* Code for Firefox */
  color: var(--purple-theme);
  background: var(--green-theme);
}
::selection {
  color: var(--purple-theme);
  background: var(--green-theme);
}
input:focus,
option:focus,
select:focus {
  outline-color: var(--lightgreen-theme);
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
table,
select,
input,
a {
  color: whitesmoke;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="number"] {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid var(--green-theme);
  background-color: transparent;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 15px;
}
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  border: 1px solid var(--green-theme);
  background-color: var(--green-theme);
  color: var(--purple-theme);
  text-decoration-style: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}

/* ------grid container------ */
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
input[type="date"] {
  height: 100%;
}
.grid_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
.grid {
  background-color: var(--purple-theme);
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
}
.inside > span {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
.item2 {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 5 / 7;
}
.item4 {
  grid-column: 7 / 9;
}

.item5 {
  grid-column: 1 / 9;
}

.inside {
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: none;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 1 / 9;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}
.inside input[type="text"] {
  width: 200px;
}
.item2 select,
.item2 option {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: var(--purple-theme);
  border: 1px solid var(--green-theme);
  text-align: center;
}
.item2 select option {
  background: var(--purple-theme);
}
.item2 table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.details table:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.details {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.item2 th {
  background-color: var(--green-theme);
  color: var(--purple-theme);
  padding: 15px;
}
.item2 a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* main edit here start */
                      #text-area td:nth-child(1) {
                        width: 80%;
                      }
                      #text-area td:nth-child(2) {
                        width: 20%;
                      }
                      #text-area thead th:nth-child(1) {
                        width: 80%;
                      }
                      #text-area thead th:nth-child(2) {
                        width: 20%;
                      }

                      #text-area thead {
                        display: block;
                      }
                      #text-area tbody {
                        height: 440px;
                        display: block;
                        overflow: auto;
                        width: 100%;
                      }
                      #text-area input {
                        width: 100%;
                      }

                      #text-area input {
                        border: none;
                      }
                      #text-area {
                        border: 1px solid var(--green-theme);
                      }
                      #text-area tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
                        background: var(--lightpurple-theme);
                      }
                      #text-area td:nth-child(4) {
                        border-right: none;
                      }
                      #text-area td {
                        border-right: 1px solid var(--green-theme);
                      }
/* main edit here ends */
.item2 .inside table * {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.suggestion {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--purple-theme);
  font-size: smaller;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.suggestion_i:hover {
  color: var(--purple-theme);
  background-color: var(--green-theme);
}
.suggestion_i {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-justify: center;
  padding: 10px 10px -5px 10px;
}
#sorted_div {
  background-color: var(--purple-theme);
  /*position:absolute;*/
  top: 123px;
}
#sorted_div tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background: var(--lightpurple-theme);
}
```

```html
        <div class="grid_container">
          <div class="grid item2">
            <div class="inside" id="topTableID">
              <form action="php/invoiceFetch.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='myForm' onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td><label for="">Location :</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="invoice_name" id="invoice_name" onchange="invoiceSpliter()" onkeyup="customerSearch(this.value)" style="width: 500;"></td>
                    <td><label>Product Suggestion : </label></td>
                    <td>
                      <div id="product_suggestion" class="suggestion"></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div id="suggestion" class="suggestion"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="details">
              <table id="text-area">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th><label>Product Name</label></th>
                    <th><label>Current Locations</label></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="addInside_tr_20">
                    <!--there will be some rows added here -->
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" tabindex="-1"></td>
                  <td><input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = 'block';" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

---

### You can check the code on [codepen]{https://codepen.io/zaidi2293/pen/WNwmJrP} (Ignore most of the css as they are just to replicate what I had so that I don't miss something out)

---

(Sorry for the extensive code length) The Problem is the "thead" is not aligned with "tbody" as in column perspective because of overflow in vertical direction. I've asked this question before but that doesn't seem to work for me. Also, there will be some more columns added in the future. **No custom size width answers please**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may reset the `table-layout` to `fixed`, turn `tr` into tables and apply the width to each cells, then add a 1.2em padding or margin right on `thead` *(average width of a scrollbar)*.

answer inspired from [How to set tbody height with overflow scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989463/how-to-set-tbody-height-with-overflow-scroll/23989771#23989771) and <del>probably</del> a duplicate.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
}

tr {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#text-area {
  border: 1px solid;
}

#text-area tr :nth-child(1) {
  width: 15%;
}

#text-area tr :nth-child(2) {
  width: 60%;
}

#text-area tr :nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%;
}

#text-area tr :nth-child(4) {
  width: 15%;
}

#text-area thead {
  display: block;
  padding-right:1.2em;
}

#text-area tbody {
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="text-area">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><label>Barcode</label></th>
      <th><label>Product Name</label></th>
      <th><label>Count</label></th>
      <th><label>QB-Price / Online Price</label></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696001844"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="ACTIVATED CHARCOAL (COCONUT BASE) 114g"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696023815"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BILBERRY FRUIT POWDER"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696031100"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BLADDERWRACK C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696031100"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BLADDERWRACK C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696031100"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BLADDERWRACK C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696037607"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BUCKTHORN BARK C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696044803"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="CASCARA BARK C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696044803"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="CASCARA BARK C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696042007"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="CHAMOMILE FLOWER WHOLE"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="6"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696066805"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DAMIANA LVS. C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696066805"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DAMIANA LVS. C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696067208"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DANDELION LVS. C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696067208"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DANDELION LVS. C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696084007"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="FRANKINCENSE TEARS"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="4"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696087008"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="GENTIAN ROOT C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696087008"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="GENTIAN ROOT C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696108208"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="HIBISCUS FLOWER WHOLE"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="6"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696112809"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="HYSSOP HERB POWDER"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696124604"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="LICORICE ROOT C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696124604"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="LICORICE ROOT C/S"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for that information. Although it did solve the asked problem but it ruined the alignment again. For some reason my thead and tbody dose not want to work together. I've followed you suggestion from the related question you've answered but same problem. @G-Cyrillus

Comment: @SaadSaiyed do you have an example where it goes wrong ? which browser(s) are you using ? would position:sticky be fine for you to use ? possible example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOPpxjP

Comment: I am using Chrome as default and position:sticky is not working for me. I did not see the header of the table sticking up in your example here: [https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOPpxjP](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOPpxjP). Also I have to be care about the width of my div in which this table exists for responsive design. I can provide you with my online website link if that can give you better idea about my need. But genuinely thanks for help.

Comment: oh yes, th need to be the sticky ones :update at  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOPpxjP

Answer (score 0):

You could set input box width 100% and add pixels width to th and td, instead of percentages.,
The input box width 100% will help to set it to its parent width and remove its default width. The pixels can help to have a fixed width and alignment problems.

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid;
}
#text-area{
  border: 1px solid;
}

#text-area td:nth-child(1){
  width: 100px;
}
#text-area td:nth-child(2){
  width: 200px;
}
#text-area td:nth-child(3){
  width: 100px;
}
#text-area td:nth-child(4){
  width: 100px;
}

#text-area thead th:nth-child(1){
  width: 100px;
}
#text-area thead th:nth-child(2){
  width: 200px;
}
#text-area thead th:nth-child(3){
  width: 100px;
}
#text-area thead th:nth-child(4){
  width: 100px;
}
   

#text-area thead{
  display:block;
}
#text-area  tbody{
  height:200px;
  display:block;
  overflow:auto;
}
  #text-area input{
width:100%
}
```

```html
<table id="text-area">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><label >Barcode</label></th>
      <th><label >Product Name</label></th>
      <th><label >Count</label></th>
      <th><label >QB-Price / Online Price</label></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696001844"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="ACTIVATED CHARCOAL (COCONUT BASE) 114g" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696023815"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BILBERRY FRUIT POWDER" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696031100"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BLADDERWRACK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696031100"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BLADDERWRACK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696031100"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BLADDERWRACK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696037607"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BUCKTHORN BARK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696044803"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="CASCARA BARK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696044803"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="CASCARA BARK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696042007"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="CHAMOMILE FLOWER WHOLE" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="6" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696066805"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DAMIANA LVS. C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696066805"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DAMIANA LVS. C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696067208"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DANDELION LVS. C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696067208"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DANDELION LVS. C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696084007"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="FRANKINCENSE TEARS" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="4" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696087008"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="GENTIAN ROOT C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696087008"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="GENTIAN ROOT C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696108208"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="HIBISCUS FLOWER WHOLE" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="6" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696112809"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="HYSSOP HERB POWDER" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="2" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696124604"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="LICORICE ROOT C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696124604"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="LICORICE ROOT C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but I think so that does not work for me @vishnu

Answer (score 0):

```css
th {
  background-color: #fff;
}


th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<table id="text-area">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><label >Barcode</label></th>
      <th><label >Product Name</label></th>
      <th><label >Count</label></th>
      <th><label >QB-Price / Online Price</label></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696001844"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="ACTIVATED CHARCOAL (COCONUT BASE) 114g" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696023815"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BILBERRY FRUIT POWDER" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696031100"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BLADDERWRACK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696031100"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BLADDERWRACK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696031100"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BLADDERWRACK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696037607"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="BUCKTHORN BARK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696044803"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="CASCARA BARK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696044803"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="CASCARA BARK C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696042007"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="CHAMOMILE FLOWER WHOLE" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="6" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696066805"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DAMIANA LVS. C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696066805"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DAMIANA LVS. C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696067208"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DANDELION LVS. C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696067208"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="DANDELION LVS. C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696084007"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="FRANKINCENSE TEARS" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="4" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696087008"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="GENTIAN ROOT C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696087008"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="GENTIAN ROOT C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696108208"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="HIBISCUS FLOWER WHOLE" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="6" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696112809"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="HYSSOP HERB POWDER" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="2" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696124604"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="LICORICE ROOT C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="772696124604"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="LICORICE ROOT C/S" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="$19.25" ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `position:sticky` is the way nowdays, it requires a wrapper with a set height. I would upvote if the snippet did mimic entirely the result expected, also  with a little explanation. The snippet in fullpage mode doesn't scroll atall ;)

Comment: Same problem not aligning properly with my rest of the design. But thanks for the suggestion, I learned something new from this @Gaurav