# Keep the first row at the top of the Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do I keep `#first` at the top?

```html
    <div class="table">
        <table class="maintable">
            <tbody>
                <tr id="first">
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

> CSS Code

```css
 .table{
    grid-row: 2/9;
    margin-right: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    overflow: scroll;
 }
 tr{
    height: 61px;
 }
 table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 #first{
    position: fixed;
 }
 tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fefefe;
 }
 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #fafafa;
 }
```

I've tried using `<thead>` and `<th>` however because my table is **inside a div**, which is responsive and doesn't have a set height, I've had problems.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8423768/102937) what you're asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.

1. A html table can have multiple tbody's. Each tbody could be styled differently. Something I found out after I used a different approach.
2. Use a separate table for the fixed part and the variable part. I used this to have a fixed header and a scrollable content. In order to have the columns lineup I use a colgroup. If you try to do this in PHP than this function might be helpful. It creates a article section for the scrollable content. Property $colwidths is an array with widths, property field_names an array of heading labels:

   ```
    protected function write_table_header() {?>
    <header>
        <h1><?= $this-> tabletitle ?></h1>
        <table class="report-table">
                <col width="<?= implode('" /><col width="',$this->colwidths ) ?>" />
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><?= implode( '</th><th>', $this-> field_names ) ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </header>
    <article>
        <table class="report-table">
            <col width="<?= implode('" /><col width="',$this->colwidths ) ?>" />
   ```

after which you can loop over your table content.

Comment: I didn't use your PHP code, however I inferred from your answer that I could set the header as a **separate table**. This works great.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding top:0; to #first.
Im not sure if this is what you meant though.

```css
.table{
    grid-row: 2/9;
    margin-right: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
tr{
    height: 61px;
}
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#first{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fefefe;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
                        <table class="maintable">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr id="first">
                                    <td>Hello</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Hello</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Hello</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Hello</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Hello</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Hello</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Hello</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Hello</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Pretty. the empty scrollbars in the content should be removed with a overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 0):

I hope this responsive table will solve your, problem have a look

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Hello</th>
      <th>Hello</th>
      <th>Hello</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```