# How to display scroll bar onto a html table

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, overflow

I am writing a page where I need an html table to maintain a set size. I need the headers at the top of the table to stay there at all times but I also need the body of the table to scroll no matter how many rows are added to the table.

I want it to look like method 2 in this url: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/tablescroll.html

I have tried doing this but no scrollbar appears:

```css
tbody {
  height: 80em;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<table border=1 id="qandatbl" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th class="col1">Question No</th>
    <th class="col2">Option Type</th>
    <th class="col1">Duration</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='qid'></td>
      <td class="options"></td>
      <td class="duration"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the code from the example method?  You can't use `<tbody>` unfortunately.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/TweNm/

The idea is to wrap the `<table>` in a non-statically positioned `<div>` which has an `overflow:auto` CSS property. Then position the elements in the `<thead>` absolutely.

```css
#table-wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
#table-scroll {
  height:150px;
  overflow:auto;  
  margin-top:20px;
}
#table-wrapper table {
  width:100%;

}
#table-wrapper table * {
  background:yellow;
  color:black;
}
#table-wrapper table thead th .text {
  position:absolute;   
  top:-20px;
  z-index:2;
  height:20px;
  width:35%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="table-wrapper">
  <div id="table-scroll">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><span class="text">A</span></th>
                <th><span class="text">B</span></th>
                <th><span class="text">C</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr> <td>1, 0</td> <td>2, 0</td> <td>3, 0</td> </tr>
          <tr> <td>1, 1</td> <td>2, 1</td> <td>3, 1</td> </tr>
          <tr> <td>1, 2</td> <td>2, 2</td> <td>3, 2</td> </tr>
          <tr> <td>1, 3</td> <td>2, 3</td> <td>3, 3</td> </tr>
          <tr> <td>1, 4</td> <td>2, 4</td> <td>3, 4</td> </tr>
          <tr> <td>1, 5</td> <td>2, 5</td> <td>3, 5</td> </tr>
          <tr> <td>1, 6</td> <td>2, 6</td> <td>3, 6</td> </tr>
          <tr> <td>1, 7</td> <td>2, 7</td> <td>3, 7</td> </tr>
          <tr> <td>1, 8</td> <td>2, 8</td> <td>3, 8</td> </tr>
          <tr> <td>1, 9</td> <td>2, 9</td> <td>3, 9</td> </tr>
          <tr> <td>1, 10</td> <td>2, 10</td> <td>3, 10</td> </tr>
          <!-- etc... -->
          <tr> <td>1, 99</td> <td>2, 99</td> <td>3, 99</td> </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about no width-fixed columns?

Comment: I tried your answer but header columns are not aligned. I used only your css in a style tag inside the body tag where I copied your table

Comment: Great solution, but I am having problems with it. When try to hide a row and set display:none there are some white spaces between rows. That is not the case with the regular table.
Any ideas, tips or suggestions?

Comment: @Antonio: I had the same problem (centered* header columns seeming non-aligned), but adding `transform: translateX(-50%)` did the trick for me [*centered being the standard styling in Firefox which is removed by the „normalize CSS“ option in this answer's JSFiddle]

Answer (score 65):

You have to insert your `<table>` into a `<div>` that it has fixed size, and in `<div>` style you have to set `overflow: scroll`.

**Update**:

The original answer was written 10 years ago. These days there are lots of good UI components for table views and showing in proper ways. So my suggestion is to go for one of these free or paid components to make sure you already support lots of edge cases which is already implemented in these components.

Comment: gave height as 500px for my div and it worked fine. <div style="overflow:scroll; height:500px;">

Comment: Don't know why everyone made it so complicated. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution. There may be caveats to adding a div with an overflow and fixed height but this solution will at least set you in the right direction.

Comment: Superb answer mate! Cheers to you :)-

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple, straight to the point and I do not destroy anything else with it.

Comment: I believe that this solution won't work because the header of the table will disappear if the table is scrolled too far. This does not satisfy the requirements of the original post, which says to keep the headers in place at all times.

Comment: @richnis, the answer need to update, I update that.

Answer (score 41):

The accepted answer provided a good starting point, but if you resize the frame, change the column widths, or even change the table data, the headers will get messed up in various ways. Every other example I've seen has similar issues, or imposes some serious restrictions on the table's layout.

I think I've finally got all these problems solved, though. It took a *lot* of CSS, but the final product is about as reliable and easy to use as a normal table.

Here's an example that has all the required features to replicate the table referenced by the OP: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doctorDestructo/x54uraaq/)**

The colors and borders would have to be changed to make it identical to the reference. Information on how to make those kinds of changes is provided in the CSS comments.

Here's the code:

```css
/*the following html and body rule sets are required only if using a % width or height*/
/*html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}*/
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
.scrollingtable {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto; /*if you want a fixed width, set it here, else set to auto*/
  min-width: 0/*100%*/; /*if you want a % width, set it here, else set to 0*/
  height: 188px/*100%*/; /*set table height here; can be fixed value or %*/
  min-height: 0/*104px*/; /*if using % height, make this large enough to fit scrollbar arrows + caption + thead*/
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0; /*need enough padding to make room for caption*/
  text-align: left;
}
.scrollingtable * {box-sizing: border-box;}
.scrollingtable > div {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px; /*this determines column header height*/
}
.scrollingtable > div:before {
  top: 0;
  background: cornflowerblue; /*header row background color*/
}
.scrollingtable > div:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div {
  min-height: 0/*43px*/; /*if using % height, make this large enough to fit scrollbar arrows*/
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll/*auto*/; /*set to auto if using fixed or % width; else scroll*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black; /*border around table body*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div:after {background: white;} /*match page background color*/
.scrollingtable > div > div > table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-top: -20px; /*inverse of column header height*/
  /*margin-right: 17px;*/ /*uncomment if using % width*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px; /*inverse of caption height*/
  margin-top: -1px; /*inverse of border-width*/
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > * > tr > * {padding: 0;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 6px 0 6px; /*header cell padding*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > :first-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
  border-left: 1px solid black; /*leftmost header border*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div > div:first-child,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * + :before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  color: white; /*header row font color*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:after {content: attr(label);}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * + :before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  min-height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
  padding-top: 1px;
  border-left: 1px solid black; /*borders between header cells*/
}
.scrollingtable .scrollbarhead {float: right;}
.scrollingtable .scrollbarhead:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: -1px; /*inverse border-width*/
  background: white; /*match page background color*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:after {
  content: "";
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  top: -1px; /*inverse of border width*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody {vertical-align: top;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr {background: white;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
  height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody:last-of-type > tr:last-child > * {border-bottom: none;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {background: gainsboro;} /*alternate row color*/
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * + * {border-left: 1px solid black;} /*borders between body cells*/
```

```html
<div class="scrollingtable">
  <div>
    <div>
      <table>
        <caption>Top Caption</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><div label="Column 1"></div></th>
            <th><div label="Column 2"></div></th>
            <th><div label="Column 3"></div></th>
            <th>
              <!--more versatile way of doing column label; requires 2 identical copies of label-->
              <div><div>Column 4</div><div>Column 4</div></div>
            </th>
            <th class="scrollbarhead"/> <!--ALWAYS ADD THIS EXTRA CELL AT END OF HEADER ROW-->
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    Faux bottom caption
  </div>
</div>

<!--[if lte IE 9]><style>.scrollingtable > div > div > table {margin-right: 17px;}</style><![endif]-->
```

Comment: awesome job. I have a table with 15 columns, however, and I can't seem to contain the table to the page without a horizontal scrollbar now too. I've tried tweaking your css, your beautifully coded css, to accomodate more dynamic width'd columns but nothing I change other than table width makes a difference. If I change table width to 100%, then the table renders in the width of the table, but because the column widths won't wrap I still can not see all 15 columns of data. I almost have a scrolling table that looks way-kewl, so any help appreciated.

Comment: oh wait a sec, no horizontal scrollbar, the table just cuts off.

Comment: @nanker If you need horizontal scrolling and are willing to use a tiny bit of JavaScript, you should check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25902860/2759272). It's the best way to do a scrolling table that I'm aware of. There was no good way to do horizontal scrolling with just CSS back when I posted this answer, but I haven't looked into it for a while so I don't know what's possible now.

Comment: Awesome work.  Could you comment on how to tweak for multiple header rows?  Simply repeating the `<tr><th></th>..</tr>` construct clearly does not work.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh A multi-row header would be tricky using this technique. Adding rows would be easy, but I'm not sure how you'd get the horizontal borders between them. You might want to try the JavaScript solution I linked in my previous comment unless you can't use JS for some reason.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure why no one mentioned to just use the built-in sticky header style for  elements. Worked great for me.

```
.tableContainerDiv {
   overflow: auto;
   max-height: 80em;
}
th {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   background: white;
}
```

Put a min-width on the  in @media if you need to make responsive (or similar).

see [Table headers position:sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166162/table-headers-positionsticky-and-border-issue) or [Position Sticky and Table Headers](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/)

Comment: This is a cleaner, approach, closer to original tables, with a minimal amount of css.  The other answers are outdated.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved this problem by separating my content into two tables.

One table is the header row.

The seconds is also `<table>` tag, but wrapped by `<div>` with static height and overflow scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Worth noting, that depending on your purpose (mine was the autofill results of a searchbar) you may want the height to be changeable, and for the scrollbar to only exist if the height exceeds that.

If you want that, replace `height: x;` with `max-height: x;`, and `overflow:scroll` with `overflow:auto`.

Additionally, you can use `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` if you want, and obviously the same thing works horizontally with `width : x;`

Answer (score 2):

If you get to the point where all the mentioned solutions don't work (as it got for me), do this:

- Create two tables. One for the header and another for the body
- Give the two tables different parent containers/divs
- Style the second table's div to allow vertical scroll of its contents.

Like this, in your `HTML`

```
<div class="table-header-class">
    <table>
       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Ava</th>
            <th>Alexis</th>
            <th>Mcclure</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="table-content-class">
   <table>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>I am the boss</td>
            <td>No, da-da is not the boss!</td>
            <td>Alexis, I am the boss, right?</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then style the second table's parent to allow vertical scroll, in your `CSS`

```
    .table-content-class {
        overflow-y: scroll;    // use auto; or scroll; to allow vertical scrolling; 
        overflow-x: hidden;    // disable horizontal scroll 
    }
```

Comment: This is the same implementation as Zvi's answer a year prior.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy, just wrap the table in a div that has `overflow-y:scroll;` and `overflow-x:scroll` properties, and make the div have a width and length smaller than the table.
IT WILL WORK!!!

Comment: Okay, I will add it in the next answer.

Comment: Okay, did it, I don't yet know how to indent code properly yet on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS:
`div{ overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:scroll; width:20px; height:30px; } table{ width:50px; height:50px; }`

You can make the table and the DIV around the table be any size you want, just make sure that the DIV is smaller than the table.
You MUST contain the table inside of the DIV.

Answer (score -1):

just add on table

```
style="overflow-x:auto;"
```

```html
<table border=1 id="qandatbl" align="center" style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <tr>
    <th class="col1">Question No</th>
    <th class="col2">Option Type</th>
    <th class="col1">Duration</th>
    </tr>

   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class='qid'></td>
    <td class="options"></td>
    <td class="duration"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

style="overflow-x:auto;"`

Comment: The question was how to make a table body scroll vertically while the column header stays put.