# Scroll bar not appearing in html table

Tags: html, css, overflow

I searched for similar question and found some but the answers did not help. So I am posting it. Below is the code. When i have lot of records the scroll bar is not shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Adding the CSS also

```
.content-cardnumber
{
    margin-left: auto;
    color:rgba(47,130,194,.8);
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
.content-origintime
{
    margin-left: 110px;
    color:rgba(47,130,194,.8);
    text-align:center;
}
.content-eventcode
{
    margin-left: 130px;
    color:rgba(47,130,194,.8);
    text-align:center;
    width:200px;
}
.content-readername
{
    margin-left: 150px;
    color:rgba(47,130,194,.8);
    text-align:center;
}
.events-table
{
    background-color:#aacef6;
    overflow:auto;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List of Alarms</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>View</h2>
        <div style="overflow-y:auto">
            <table class="events-table" style="overflow-y:auto">
                <tr>
                    <th class="content-cardnumber">Card Number</th>
                    <th class="content-eventcode">Event Code</th>
                    <th class="content-origintime">Event Time</th>            
                </tr>

                @foreach (IEvent e in Model.EventList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="content-cardnumber">@e.CardNumber</td>
                        <td class="content-eventcode">@e.EventCode</td>
                        <td class="content-origintime">@e.EventOriginTime</td>

                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why so many down votes? I have added the CSS now. Sorry for not adding it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set a height for either the div or the table and only one overflow is required:

```
    <div style="overflow-y:auto; height: 400px;">
        <table class="events-table">
```

A table can't be made scrollable. But check out this answer: [How to display scroll bar onto a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table)

Comment: Thanks this works! If i set the overflow and the height to the table and remove the div the scroll bar does not show up though?

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll the  div not table  so by this  use code

```
 <div style="overflow-y:scroll;height:100px;">
        <table class="events-table" style="overflow-y:scroll;height:100px;">
            <tr>
                <th class="content-cardnumber">Card Number</th>
                <th class="content-eventcode">Event Code</th>
                <th class="content-origintime">Event Time</th>            
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <th class="content-cardnumber">Card Number</th>
                <th class="content-eventcode">Event Code</th>
                <th class="content-origintime">Event Time</th>            
            </tr> <tr>
                <th class="content-cardnumber">Card Number</th>
                <th class="content-eventcode">Event Code</th>
                <th class="content-origintime">Event Time</th>            
            </tr>

            @foreach (IEvent e in Model.EventList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="content-cardnumber">@e.CardNumber</td>
                    <td class="content-eventcode">@e.EventCode</td>
                    <td class="content-origintime">@e.EventOriginTime</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="content-cardnumber">@e.CardNumber</td>
                    <td class="content-eventcode">@e.EventCode</td>
                    <td class="content-origintime">@e.EventOriginTime</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="content-cardnumber">@e.CardNumber</td>
                    <td class="content-eventcode">@e.EventCode</td>
                    <td class="content-origintime">@e.EventOriginTime</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="content-cardnumber">@e.CardNumber</td>
                    <td class="content-eventcode">@e.EventCode</td>
                    <td class="content-origintime">@e.EventOriginTime</td>

                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>
```