# CSS Overflow Scroll bar was appear but Not Working

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I Have done one example with css overflow property.In this example i got one problem with overflow scroll.**The scroll bar was appear, but not working** means whenever moves cursor to scroll bar,In this time the scroll bar is not active.I didn't get any idea about this so please help me.And **Click bottom edge of scroll bar then it works otherwise not works**.

```
CSS Code :

thead, tbody
 {
    display: block;
}

tbody 
{
width:750px;
height:400px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Here i have updated table rows means **tbody** dynamically with the help of js.

```
HTML Code :

<div id="table">
           <div id="tablelayout">
                <div id="tmenu">
                 <table id="table"> 
                  <thead>
                  <tr id="trmenu">

                     <th>Table Id</th>
                     <th>Game Type</th>
                     <th>Bet</th>
                     <th>Status</th>
                     <th>Total Players</th>

                   </tr>

                   </thead>
                   <tbody>


                   </tbody>

                </table>
                </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can we have some code please

Comment: You must post the html too

Comment: Possible Duplicate --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table

Comment: yes i posted code can you check once please?  @Mr.Alien

Comment: With Jquery :- http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/2/

Comment: Even not working . @ Anup

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code

```
tbody 
    {
    width:750px;
    height:400px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    }
```