# Wrappable Table Headers in HTML/CSS via the scrollingTable example

Tags: html, css

I was looking at this topic:  [How to display scroll bar onto a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table).

The scrollingTable example by doctorDesctructo.

I am trying to enhance this wonderful table example, but modify it to allow the use of multi-row-text header columns?  Currently, the table attempts to expand each column width based on the label="text here" attribute.  Is there a way to allow wrapping, even if I had to manually specify a height of the header?

Instead of a single-row table header that looks like:

```
text here
```

I would like to have two rows of text:

```
text
here
```

I can expand the height of the header within the CSS, but the text won't wrap.

Comment: Can you include the html and css you're using, so we can try to give you more specific guidance? Going a little further, you could also add your code to a jsFiddle so that others can tweak it and show you what is going on in an interactive way. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Well, that is why I entered the URL link.  All of the code and a jsFiddle example is already there.  As I said, normally I would have just responded to the original post and asked a question, but I don't have the rights.  If you can't find the example, I'm talking about, let me know and I'll re-post everything.  I assumed that was a no-no.

Comment: Linking to the other post is fine, but it's usually good form to post the parts you've tried to show what you've done to attempt the fix on your own.