# Bootstrap table fixed header align with <tbody> issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a fixed header on Bootstrap table with CSS.

**CSS**

```
table.scroll tbody, table.scroll thead {
    display: block;
}

table.scroll tbody {
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="standart_list" class="table table-bordered scroll">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Standart Kodu</th>
            <th>Standart Tanımı</th>
            <th>Standart(Asgari Şart)</th>
            <th>Standart Durum Karşılanıyor Mu?</th>
            <th>Mevcut Durum</th>
            <th>Açıklama</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr bgcolor="#7fffd4">
            <td>
                ADLİ TIP
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="brans_2882" value="2">
            <td>
                2.1.1
            </td>
            <td style="max-width: 600px">
                EĞİTİCİ SAYISI
            </td>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="select_2882" id="select_2882" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">Evet</option>
                    <option value="0" selected="">Hayır</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="input_2882" id="input_2882" value="0" class="form-control mevcut_durum numeric" required="">
                <span class="errmsg"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="text_2882" id="text_2882" class="form-control aciklama" required="">bu büyüklüğe</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`<tbody>` looks good and scrolling works. But `<thead>` elements do not align with `<tbody>`.

How can I solve this?

Here is screen which looks as described:

[image: table example]

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your demo link?

Comment: I fixed the formatting a bit, you might spot the problems yourself now.

Comment: @IshimdarAhamad I gave the codes. You can test it.

Comment: You can use Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The below works on browsers newer than IE9, to get it to work in older browsers you will need to use fixed column widths unfortunatley.
Source: [Source page for my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap)

```css
table {
        width: 100%;
    }

thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

thead th {
    height: 30px;

    /*text-align: left;*/
}

tbody {
    height: 120px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

thead {
    /* fallback */
}


tbody td, thead th {
    width: 19.2%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this part:

```
table.scroll tbody,
table.scroll thead { display: block; }
```

Comment: As you can see ,its not aligned width tbody.

Comment: where is the fiddler link?

Comment: If I remove this, table not scrolling

Comment: I think you have to go for javaScript to fix this issue . i found below on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in a previous stackoverflow post.
[Scrollable table with fixed header in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap) with solution fiddle in second comment.

Another solution:
[How to display scroll bar onto a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table)

Comment: I added many rows  but it doesnt help me.If we remove display block then scroll bar won't show.

Comment: Dear friends , this scroll normal page scroll. I want to fixed table header.And only table body has scroll.Thanks your effort but this is not solution

Comment: Sorry for my previous posts and comments. I misunderstood you. I deleted the comments and edited the answer. Found solution in another s.o. post.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line of code in your tabel tag, it'll fix the issue

```
<table data-toggle="table" id="standart_list" class="table table-bordered scroll">[enter image description here][1]
```