# Chorme after button click event Scroll bar not displaying?

Tags: c#, html, css, scrollbar

After uploading a document in my page, the document automatically refreshed. Tho after refreshing the page scroll bar disappear?

See this images:

In page load scroll bar is visible,
[Before Imgage][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3szo.png

After page refresh scrolling not visible

[After Image][2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhD7f.png

How can i fix this issue?

My code :

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="overflow-y:scroll !important; height:auto">
```

Comment: I don't see any code after your `My code:` can you please fix this?

Comment: now can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

Since the table is only displaying 1 content and not multiple contents there's no need to have a Scroll Bar. While having the `height: auto;`  the scroll bar should display when you upload multiple files.

You may try to use the code in this form;

```
<table style="overflow-y:auto; width:100%; height:auto">
```

You might also check the following post: [How to display scroll bar onto a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table)

Comment: no,actually i have more content inside table for example i displayed the image

Comment: @Elina Try to add the width:100% inside the style sheet. And overflow-y:auto to auto

Comment: I tried its not working can you please see the second image when i was uploading document i was displayed the documents in Gridview.Once the document is uploaded the scroll bar is not visible.If i remove the document  the scroll bar is visible

Comment: It was working fine in Internet explorer .Only problem with chorome.

Comment: Can you try to add 'position: relative; overflow:visible;' to the style? and see if it works.

Comment: What are you trying to do actually? In your tag you mentioned C# yet you posted HTML and CSS Codes? Skype?

Comment: I am using table in my aspx page