# Chrome css position absolute for freezing table headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I currently have two tables that is on top of each other. the front table only shows it's header and the body is hidden using the css "visibility:hidden". this table is using "position:absolute" to make it freeze in place, the table is a complete clone of the 2nd table.

As i was testing on IE, the dropdown and link on the tbody of the 2nd table is working fine but when i tested it on chrome, the 2nd table cannot be clicked as it was blocked by the hidden table  body in-front of it.

Are there any alternatives that i can use to implement the freezing of headers on chrome?

Note: The data that will be loaded is dynamically with different sizes. the width of each column will be adjusted accordingly.

Here is a sample code but this works fine on fiddle but won't be working when used as html file and run on chrome: https://fiddle.jshell.net/3poz4o4q/3/

Added the whole HTML file that i tested with. 
Got the jquery from here http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js
and saved it on the file name "jquery-1.9.1.min.js" and referenced it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function onLoad() {
    var cloneData = $('#actualData tr').clone(false);
    $("#sampleData").append(cloneData);

    var cloneHeader = $('#behindHeader tr').clone();
    $("#showingHeader").append(cloneHeader);

    $("#sampleData").css("visibility", "collapse");
    $("#behindHeader").css("visibility", "collapse");

    $("#tableHeader").css("position", "absolute");
}
</script>
<body onload="onLoad()">
<div class="table-header" id="tableHeader">
    <table class="editableTable" id="editTable" border="1">
        <thead id="showingHeader"/>
        <tbody id="sampleData"/>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="table-body" id="tableBody">
    <table class="editableTable" id="bodytable" border="1">
        <thead id="behindHeader">
                            <tr id="entity-header">
                <th colspan="13">
                    <a id="Create Something">Create Something</a>
                    <a id="Create another thing">Create another thing</a>
                    <a href="#" id="save">Save</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="column-headers">
                <th id="data link">data link</th>
                <th id="data 1">data 1</th>
                <th id="data 2">data 2</th>
                <th id="data 3">data 3</th>
                <th id="data 4">data 4</th>
                <th id="data 5">data 5</th>
                <th id="data 6">data 6</th>
                <th id="drop down 1">drop down 1</th>
                <th><span id="checkbox 1">checkbox 1</span></th>
                <th id="drop down 2">drop down 2</th>
                <th><span id="checkbox 2">checkbox 2</span></th>
                <th id="drop down 3">drop down 3</th>
                <th><span id="checkbox 3">checkbox 3</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="actualData">
            <tr id="actual id" class="modified">
                <td ><a href="#" >Data ID</a></td>
                <td >Data Description 1</td>
                <td >Data Description 2</td>
                <td >Data Description 3</td>
                <td >Data Description 4</td>
                <td >Data Description 6</td>
                <td >Data Description 7</td>
                <td >
                    <select>
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select></td>
                <td >
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input id="1" type="checkbox"><label for="1"></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <select>
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select></td>
                <td >
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input id="2" type="checkbox"><label for="2"></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <select disabled="disabled">
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select></td>
                <td >
                    <div class="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
                        <input id="3" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"><label for="3" disabled="disabled"></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: please add your code please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display scroll bar onto a html table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table)

Comment: "Here is a sample code but this works fine on fiddle but won't be working when used as html file and run on chrome" You're probably not calling jQuery properly.

Comment: Already added the code. i created a local copy of the jquery and referenced it. 
on IE, all the links, textbox and dropdown works, but on chrome, it's unclickable.

Comment: Have you defined a z-index on the table with contents so it is above the other? (z-indexes can only be defined if the element is set to something that not "static", by the way). Alternatively you can make the hidden body set with a pointer-events: none to disable mousing over it, but you need to see browser compatibility if you use this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try 'div class="table-header" id="tableHeader" style="z-index:-1" ';
Put the header div to back;

Comment: the whole reason for the "table-header" div is to create a floating header that will stick on top of the table even if the table is scrolled down. putting the "table-header" div at the back will work for small sized table but when the table is long enough to be scrolled, the table in-front will obscure the visibility of the "table-header" div once scrolled.