# Adding a scroll bar vertically to a table

Tags: php, html, css

I want to add a scroll bar vertically to my html dynamic table. I have put my table inside a div, but it doesn't seem to be working. please help

this is my html code

```
<thead>
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="5">
            <div class="scrollit">
              <th><span>ID</span></th> 
              <th><span>Name</span></th>
              <th><span>Location</span></th>
              <th><span>Date</span></th>
              <th><span>Catagory</span></th>
           </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

php code

```
  print "<tr>"; 
  print "<td>";
  print "<div>";
  print "<td >" . $row['ID'] . "</td>"; 
  print "<td >" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
  print "<td >" . $row['Location'] . "</td>"; 
  print "<th >" . $row['Date'] . "</th>";
  print "<td >" . $row['Category'] . "</td>";    
  print "</div>";
  print "</td>";
  print "</tr>"; 
  }               
  print "</table>";
```

css code:

```
.scrollit {
  overflow:scroll;
  height:100px;
}
```

By the way, I retrieve data from the database to the table.

Comment: give class to your div in php code

Comment: You need to look into this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax error in your HTML code, Check updated snippet below

```css
.scrollit {
    width:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    height:300px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollit">
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><span>ID</span></th>
                <th><span>Name</span></th>
                <th><span>Location</span></th>
                <th><span>Date</span></th>
                <th><span>Catagory</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: my table is a dynamic one. it retrieves data from the database. it doesn't work like this

Comment: You can use your php code instead of `tbody`
You can't put a `div` in parallel of `th/td` tag

Comment: above table format is correct. wrap your tr inside while loop

Answer (score 0):

Try it something like this:

```css
.tbl_container{
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl_container">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>row1 col1</td>
      <td>row1 col2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row2 col1</td>
      <td>row2 col2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row3 col1</td>
      <td>row3 col2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```