# HTML table overflow not working

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow, oracle-apex

I want to add a scroll bar when the html table body overflows.I do not want to scroll the table header. I have these html and css codes in my oracle apex page

**HTML**

```
<div class="t-Report-wrap">
<div class="t-Report-tableWrap">
    <table class="t-Report-report" summary="tab">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="t-Report-colHead" id="CODE" align="center">Code</th>
                <th class="t-Report-colHead" id="HEAD" align="center">Head</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>            
        <tbody>
            <tr> <td > 5198 </td><td >SUSPENCE </td></tr>
            <tr> <td > 1308 </td><td >SHARE IN KNR</td></tr>
            <tr> <td > 4803 </td><td >ONE TIME </td></tr>
            <tr><td >6021</td><td >NEETHI GOODS </td></tr>
            <tr><td >6022</td><td >MANNURE STOCK </td></tr>
            <tr><td >4832</td><td >DONATION TO </td></tr>
            <tr><td >5218</td><td >CALANDER </td></tr>
            <tr><td >4829</td><td >BUILDING TAX </td></tr>
            <tr><td >5199</td><td >BICYCLE ADVANCE </td></tr>
            <tr><td >2509</td><td >BANK LOAN LT MI(SPL) </td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="t-Report-links"></div>
<table class="t-Report-pagination t-Report-pagination--bottom" role="presentation"></table> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.t-Report-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.t-Report-tableWrap {
    height:180px;
    overflow:auto;  
    margin-top:20px;
}
.t-Report-tableWrap table {
    width:100%;
}
.t-Report-tableWrap table thead th .t-Report-colHead {
    position:absolute;   
    top:-20px;
    z-index:2;
    height:20px;
    width:35%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

But with this code, the table header is also scrolling. This  was referenced from SO answer [How to display scroll bar onto a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table). Can anybody help me to find out the error in this code?

Comment: Either remove `th` or `.t-Report-colHead` from your CSS because those are targeting the same elements.

Comment: Thanks, but the headings are now overlapping.The heading  'head' is displayed over the heading 'code'.

Comment: According to the link you provided, you should wrap your `<th>` text content in `<span>` and then target those in the CSS. So something like `<th id="CODE" align="center"><span class="t-Report-colHead">Code</th>`.

Comment: ya.got it. I added the span. Now it is ok and working fine. Thank you sir.

Comment: Awesome! I'll go ahead and add this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrect as you added an extra space between `th` and `.t-Report-colHead` in `.t-Report-tableWrap table thead th .t-Report-colHead {`

However, here is a working code.

```
tr{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

thead{
  display: block;
}

tbody{
  display: block;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/bvGmWx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: works but I have to apply width:100%,  when table row is less than 100% the scroll bar stands at the left most point.

Comment: Glad that I could help. You may choose the right answer so that it would help other users. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Update your `th` HTML to include a `span`:

```
<th id="CODE" align="center"><span class="t-Report-colHead">Code</span></th>
```

And edit your CSS selectors to remove the repetitive `th`:

```
.t-Report-tableWrap table thead .t-Report-colHead
```

Answer (score 1):

Set height and add `overflow:auto;` to `.t-Report-tableWrap tbody` instead of `.t-Report-tableWrap` so that the scrolling will only effect table body.

```css
.t-Report-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.t-Report-tableWrap {  
    margin-top:20px;
}
.t-Report-tableWrap table {
    width:100%;
}
.t-Report-tableWrap table thead th .t-Report-colHead {
    position:absolute;   
    top:-20px;
    z-index:2;
    height:20px;
    width:35%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.t-Report-tableWrap tbody{
    height:180px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change css code

```css
tbody {
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;/* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}
thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, remove it from thead width */
}
t-Report-report {
    width:400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="t-Report-wrap">
  <div class="t-Report-tableWrap">
   <table class="t-Report-report" summary="tab">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th align="center" class="t-Report-colHead" id="CODE">Code</th>
      <th align="center" class="t-Report-colHead" id="HEAD">Head</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>5198</td>
      <td>SUSPENCE</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1308</td>
      <td>SHARE IN KNR</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>4803</td>
      <td>ONE TIME</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>6021</td>
      <td>NEETHI GOODS</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>6022</td>
      <td>MANNURE STOCK</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>4832</td>
      <td>DONATION TO</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>5218</td>
      <td>CALANDER</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>4829</td>
      <td>BUILDING TAX</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>5199</td>
      <td>BICYCLE ADVANCE</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>2509</td>
      <td>BANK LOAN LT MI(SPL)</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div class="t-Report-links"></div>
  <table class="t-Report-pagination t-Report-pagination--bottom" role="presentation"></table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think apex has a setup for this, see this example:

Without the setting:
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:1

With the setting:
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:12

Go to Report Attributes:
[image]

Comment: This is for interacrtive report , But I'm using tabular form.