# scroll -y bar not coming for the table

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular8

I am working on a table where I need scroll bar after 5th column. I was trying but not able to get that.

Here is my entire code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-table) ink.

How can I get overflow y scroll bar after 5th column and in the last row? The row is alone dynamic. But this is not happening.

```
 .sampletable > table{
    overflow-x: scroll
  }
```

Comment: Separate the table in two (before and after 5th row) and then use this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table

Comment: Please try to refrain from adding please-help begging into your questions. It is just clutter, and moreover, some readers may be put off by pleading. Keep it succinct please.