# onScroll in React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onscroll

I cant figure out why onScroll is not firing console.log..
 `<table className="table"  onScroll={()=>{console.log("Works")}>`
It's just not firing console.log...

Comment: Is this table scrollable or is the _document_ or higher-up container the part that's scrollable?

Comment: Does it scroll in the first place? I'm not sure tables can do this. You may have to wrap the table and put the event on that wrapping element.

Answer (score 3):

The code will work. Your table needs to be scrollable. If there's no scroll-bar, then no scrolling event will be fired. Your table needs to be scrollable and I know by default tables don't normally stretched, they become scrollable as soon as the content is too long. But you can set the scroll-bar using css. Here's just an example on how to make it work.

```js
function App()
{

  return (
    <table className="table" onScroll={()=>alert("Table Scrolled")}>
      <tr>
        <td>First Row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Second Row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Second Row</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.table{
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}


.table tr{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: thin solid blue;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: .table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 300px;
} but it is not working(

Comment: @Mr.Newt , you need to make sure that there's enough content in your form that has a height larger than 300px. otherwise, the scroll bars won't show.

Comment: Here's another example that can help you make it scrollable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table

Comment: @Mr.Newt the table needs `display: block;` otherwise it will stretch to fit in the rows. It also makes the table inaccessible so keep that in mind.

Comment: adding display:block solve the issuse :D :D .thanks guys a lot

Comment: @Mr.Newt Didn't you follow my code? Everything is there for you man. You could've solved this long time ago already lol!

Answer (score 1):

If your element doesn't "table" is not scrollable your event will simpely not happen, however if it is scrollable try to add this style to the element `overflow: scroll`