# Fixed Row Headers with CSS in an HTML Table

Tags: html, css

I have Google'd this problem, and I seem to see every variant except for what I need. I need an HTML table with fixed ROW headers. Is there a way to do this with only HTML and CSS? If not, what is the best JQuery plugin for this?

I feel like I'm asking something that someone else has HAD to have done. But everything I look at seems to be something else entirely.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding the following CSS style should help:

```
table tr
{
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: He wants fixed rows, not columns.

Comment: @PRNDL Development Studios: Thanks for that. I have edited my original post.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for fixed row HEADERS. I'm do not understand how this addresses that problem. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: Oh right. I believe I misunderstood. I thought you wanted the table headers to have a fixed height. If you are asking for the table headers to always stay fixed at the top, then this might help:http://stackoverflow.com/a/7732309/1300806.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
table { table-layout:fixed; width:100px; }
```

Comment: My hope was to create a table whose width would grow based on the number of columns I added to it. However, in the event that the width of the table grew too large, I wanted to be able to scroll left-and-right, but I want the row headers to stay in place.

Comment: I see, probably better to look for a javascript solution than a CSS one. Sorry, haven't see any that does that.