# Fix up the column headers - Outsystems

Tags: columnheader, outsystems

I am developing an application with Outsystems, where I have a list of projects specifying different attributes of project. The list is big, and when I scroll down I am able to see the contents of the list but I am not able to judge the column headers as they are not visible once you scroll down.

So is there any solution for this problem ? I have tried with a 'Fixed table' widget but it went in vain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generic *fixed table header* problem. You can solve it employing solutions that aren't specific to the OutSystems paltform. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers) or this [jQuery Plugin for Fixed header tables](http://fixedheadertable.com/).

Should you need any help with using jQuery with OutSystems, you can check the posts by João Rosado in [this thread](http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?TopicId=7548&Topic=Integration-of-jQuery).

Comment: @ Miguel Ventura - The solutions seem pretty good, I will definitely try them..thanks for your quick concern.!!