# Scrollable resizeable table with fixed headers

Tags: jquery, resizable, fixed-header-tables

I am creating a table at runtime using jQuery. 
The table comes from JSON data.
The issue is that I need to provide a fixed header to the table so that when I scroll it the header should not move. 
I know I can create 2 divs one for header only and other for table content.
I can't do this since I need the columns to be resizable also. 
Is there any jQuery plugin  or code available to do the same?

Comment: First search and then ask - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers http://fixedheadertable.com/. It is like 30 seconds of searching! And show some effort, not only "I need this ... I need that ...". We all need stuff.

Comment: @Bakudan I have already done the searching part..perhaps you need to read the question completely.. I did the fixed header part on my own.. the only issue is the require ment of resizing of columns with header being fixed...FIRST READ PROPERLY.. THEN TRY TO THINK WHAT EXACTLY DOES THE QUESTION SAYS... THEN COMMENT...

Comment: You still need to show some effort.  What have you tried?

Comment: Well.. What I did was creating a table heading in a div and then creating the table in another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [jqFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-create-table-with-fixed-headers-and-resizable-columns/) link, this will help you to create table with fixed headers and resizeable columns.