# make fixed header of first row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/uwuqut/2/edit)

```
<div id="divScroll" style="overflow-x: hidden">
    <table id="tableAppointment" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%">

            <tr>
                <td class="csstextheader" width="70px"></td>
                <td class="csstextheader" width="70px">
                    <b>Time Slot&nbsp;</b>
                </td>
                <td><b>Room 7</b></td>
                <td><b>Room 8</b></td>
                <td><b>Room 9</b></td>
                <td><b>Room 10</b></td>
            </tr>



            <tr class="csstablelisttd">
                <td width="70px">08:00AM</td>
                <td>00</td>
                <td class="csstdred">John</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>                                     
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

call on window onload

```
function resolutionIndependent()
        {
            var height;
            var tableMain;
            var divScroll;

            if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth)
            {
                height = document.body.offsetHeight;
            }
            if (document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth)
            {
                height = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
            }
            if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight)
            {
                height = window.innerHeight;
            }
            tableMain = document.getElementById('tableMain');
            divScroll = document.getElementById('divScroll');
            tableMain.style.height = parseFloat(height - 170) + 'px';
            divScroll.style.height = parseFloat(height - 170) + 'px';
            divScroll.style.overflow = "auto";
        }
 //***tableMain which is outer table of divScroll***
```

I have to make fixed header of first row ..
I m adding `style="position:fixed"` to every cell of first row. but not getting output
..How it possible

Comment: this is not possible without changing your html part if you change your html part that's possible

Comment: as like this http://tinkerbin.com/bcVK0s0N

Comment: header coloumn and content coloumn not in same line

Comment: can we give div to tr only because u take 2 tables for fixing header...and i stored id in tr coloumns means room no cells....

Comment: now set to the header coloumn and text according to your design it eaisy man

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML table with fixed headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)

Comment: I have updated my html and demo link

Comment: @lax Your html is not correct. You have used `rowspan` in few rows but missed to exclude the corresponding columns in next row.

Comment: i have done one function to remove those columns..forget that one But how i make fixed headers

Comment: Have to agree. In order for anything to work properly (ESPECIALLY with browser resize) you will have to change *some* of the html. As it stands, there is no easy (or even relatively easy) way to go about this without making it appear hacked together. The fact that you're using percentages makes this much more difficult. The closest solution you'll get is the one bezmegakapa provided and the one Jhene Knights provided (aside from the few errors in it). Can I ask why you don't want to change the html?

Comment: i want using changing html also

Answer (score 8):

Hey you can even use a simple jquery function which would give you the result without changing you html code

```
var tdWidth = $("#tableAppointment tbody tr td").width();
$("#tableAppointment thead").css({'position': 'fixed','top': '0','left': '-0.2%', 'background-color': '#f94d4d','color': '#FFFFFF','text-align': 'center','width': '100%'});

$("#tableAppointment thead tr th").width(tdWidth);
```

the working example is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6hfX/41/)

Comment: In ie cell looks like ablock but good in ff..i want in ie only 
:(

Comment: in which ie version you need coz it works -perfect in ie8 and above.

Comment: see ur jsfiddle in ie7 ie8 ie 9

Comment: why in ie 9 cells display like block

Comment: For older versions of IE to properly support `position:fixed`, make sure you have the Transitional DOCTYPE - `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: please header freeze with my demo this should work only in ie not other browser

Comment: on every td of first row i have apply this code <td width="70px" style="z-index: 99; position: relative; top: expression(document.getElementById('divScroll').scrollTop-1);
           left: expression(document.getElementById('divScroll').scrollLeft-1); background-color: #1b72a4">
           <b>Time Slot&nbsp;</b>
          </td>

Answer (score 7):

I have created the simple coding for your question.,Please refer the following to see it in action : http://jsfiddle.net/john_rock/h6hfX/1/

**HTML Part :**

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th><th>Head3</th><th>Head4</th><th>Head5</th><th>Head6</th></tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr><td>Foot1</td><td>Foot2</td><td>Foot3</td><td>Foot4</td><td>Foot5</td><td>Foot6</td></tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr><td>r1c1</td><td>r1c2</td><td>r1c3</td><td>r1c4</td><td>r1c5</td><td>r1c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td><td>r2c3</td><td>r2c4</td><td>r2c5</td><td>r2c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r3c1</td><td>r3c2</td><td>r3c3</td><td>r3c4</td><td>r3c5</td><td>r3c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r4c1</td><td>r4c2</td><td>r4c3</td><td>r4c4</td><td>r4c5</td><td>r4c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r5c1</td><td>r5c2</td><td>r5c3</td><td>r5c4</td><td>r5c5</td><td>r5c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r6c1</td><td>r6c2</td><td>r6c3</td><td>r6c4</td><td>r6c5</td><td>r6c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r7c1</td><td>r7c2</td><td>r7c3</td><td>r7c4</td><td>r7c5</td><td>r7c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r8c1</td><td>r8c2</td><td>r8c3</td><td>r8c4</td><td>r8c5</td><td>r8c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r9c1</td><td>r9c2</td><td>r9c3</td><td>r9c4</td><td>r9c5</td><td>r9c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r10c1</td><td>r10c2</td><td>r10c3</td><td>r10c4</td><td>r10c5</td><td>r10c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r11c1</td><td>r11c2</td><td>r11c3</td><td>r11c4</td><td>r11c5</td><td>r11c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r12c1</td><td>r12c2</td><td>r12c3</td><td>r12c4</td><td>r12c5</td><td>r12c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r13c1</td><td>r13c2</td><td>r13c3</td><td>r13c4</td><td>r13c5</td><td>r13c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r14c1</td><td>r14c2</td><td>r14c3</td><td>r14c4</td><td>r14c5</td><td>r14c6</td></tr>
<tr><td>r15c1</td><td>r15c2</td><td>r15c3</td><td>r15c4</td><td>r15c5</td><td>r15c6</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>​
```

**CSS Part :**

```
table {width:100%; border:1px solid #000000;}
thead {background-color:#000268;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center; position:fixed; top:0px;}
thead th { height:50px; width:120px; text-align:center;border-width: 1px;border-style: outset;}
tbody {color:#000000;text-align:center; height:150px; overflow: scroll; margin:0px;}
tbody td { height:60px; width:100px;border-width: 1px;border-style: outset;}
tfoot {background-color:#000268; color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center; position:fixed; bottom:0px;}
tfoot td { height:50px; width:120px; text-align:center;border-width: 1px;border-style: outset;}​
```

I think this may help you resolve your problem.

Note : This is an Example Answer of your question.

Comment: Sure.,i did that too..please refer the following location : http://jsfiddle.net/john_rock/b4RGS/1/

Comment: header is not fixed John please look again

Comment: Hi lax.,i think now everything solved, please refer the following location : http://jsfiddle.net/john_rock/QcwYw/

Comment: header height,width,border not mix ups with table cells John

Comment: John i dont need tfoot and jsbin.com/idikeq/1/edit header not fix in ie 7

Comment: can  please see my quetions jsbin demo

Comment: I did my best i think.,please refer the following location : http://jsbin.com/oluyus/4/edit and also http://jsbin.com/oluyus/4/

Comment: on every td of first row i have apply this code <td width="70px" style="z-index: 99; position: relative; top: expression(document.getElementById('divScroll').scrollTop-1); left: expression(document.getElementById('divScroll').scrollLeft-1); background-color: #1b72a4"> <b>Time Slot&nbsp;</b> </td>

Answer (score 3):

If you are to use jQuery, 1st clone the table

```
var clone  = $('.tableAppointment').clone()
```

Then remove the part in the clone that is unwanted/not to be displayed in the fixed header which wiil be the clone

```
clone.remove('.csstablelisttd')
```

Then hide/remove the part that is supporst to be fixed in the table so as not create a mess , when both headers(the clone and original are displayed) and add a class to the original which we will use to refer to where we want to add the clone(before it)

```
$('.tableAppointment').remove('.firstrowclassname').addClass('beforeHeader') 
//you have not given the 1st row an ID/class, you need to, for refering in jQuery
```

Now give the clone the fixed header CSS styling and put if before the original header

```
clone.css({position: fixed}).insertBefore('.beforeHeader')
```

What you have basically done is created two headers, removed the part that is suppost to be fixed from one and removed the part that is not to be fixed from the other and displayed both together without losing their styling of the tables, only this time one table is fixed, the one with the desired rows

Answer (score 1):

can i use css for it ?
i have simple answer ...
Use `:first-child` selector like this

```
thead tr:first-child {
   position:fixed;
}
```

This is only example not ready to try ...
Change it before with your element ...
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a jQuery plugin like [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)?

Also, if the first row is meant to be a header you should use the table header tag `th`

Answer (score -3):

Try :

```
 <thead>
    <tr  style="position: fixed; background-color: grey;">
        <td class="csstextheader" width="70px"></td>
        <td class="csstextheader" width="70px">
            <b>Time Slot&nbsp;</b>
        </td>
        <td><b>Room 7</b></td>
        <td><b>Room 8</b></td>
        <td><b>Room 9</b></td>
        <td><b>Room 10</b></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Make first row as fixed position & add width for all cells with use of css it will make good

Comment: can u give me example of this without change html part

Comment: Op is saying can u do this wihtout changing html part only for css