# Freezing the top header row in an html table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

How can the CSS coding be modified, such that the first row (top header) is frozen?

The code needs to be IE7 Compliant.

```
table.dataTable {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    color: #235A81;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
table.dataTable th {
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 4px 3px 3px 4px;
    background: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#cdcdcd");
    text-align: left;
    width: 150px;
}

table.dataTable td {
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: 1px solid #999; 
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}


div.scrollTableContainer {
    height: 285px;  
    overflow: auto;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
}


div.scrollTableContainer table {
    width: 952px;
}

div.scrollTableContainer td:last-child {padding-right: 20px;}

div.scrollTableContainer tr:first-child td { border-top: 0; }

div.scrollTableContainer thead th {border-bottom: 1px solid #999; }
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uamhc/

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML table with fixed headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table with fixed headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)

Answer (score 1):

Much like what @keeg said you would need to create two tables. However if you have no control over the content of the site you can use

```
$('.flexme').flexigrid();
```

Navigate to "Example 1" of **[this](http://www.flexigrid.info/)** link to see an example of how to use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to draw two tables, one with the content, one just the header, put the header table in a div and set the div css property: `display:fixed`