# How to have a Fixed Header in a Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have this current implementation from a friend of mind.  The project has a GridView as shown below

```
<div ID="divGrid" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="docGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
    DataSourceID="pagedDatasetSourceControl" OnRowDataBound="docGrid_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanging="docGrid_SelectedIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="ID"
    CssClass="gridTable" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" meta:resourcekey="docGridResource1">
    <PagerSettings Visible="false"></PagerSettings>
    <Columns>
        ..................
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle CssClass="tableRow"></RowStyle>
    <PagerStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" HorizontalAlign="Right"></PagerStyle>
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="tableRowAlt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Now, more that one (1) .cs classes using this GridView, then each implementation is different.  Then "ONE" of the .cs class implements a "scrolling" which is shown below.

```
this.divGrid.Attributes.Add("class", "fleft scroll");
this.divGrid.Attributes.Add("style", "width:100%; height:250px;");
```

But the code above scrolls the header as well, so when I scroll down the header scrolls as well.  Is there a way to fix this issue by adding an "Attributes" in my .cs file for this class.

Thanks

Comment: Use javascript. [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers/)

Comment: Here is a prepared project for ASP.NET on codeproject that you can download: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/250669/Gridview-with-Fixed-Header

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to implement it?

Comment: Download the source on that page and see for yourself. (The src file is well commented so you'll understand what he's doing)

Comment: Hello adaam, the solution just won't work...

Answer (score 5):

i wrote jQuery plug-in can fixed header and freeze column, it can be apply to GridView.
see the image:

[image]

look the website: http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

Supported Browsers

- Internet Explorer 7, 8 (IE 9 Compatibility)
- Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112)
- Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 Preview
- Google Chrome(23.0.1271.64 m)
- Mozilla Firefox (16.0.2)
- Apple Safari (5.1.7)

Comment: Great job man! Please, add to your plugin' page that it needs jquery-ui.min.js to be installed or if not to show some message. Thank you!

Comment: I have update more information in GitHub: https://github.com/twlikol/GridViewScroll/ and v2 version was released

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution, if you add CssClass to header (ShowHeader="true"):

```
<HeaderStyle CssClass="StickyHeader" />
```

And add the following css

```
.StickyHeader th {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0
}
```

It makes stick the first row's table datas, not the row. That's why this is only an alternative solution, because the scrollbar is started from header row.. but after you styled the scrollbar a little, the result is not so bad.

[image: table sticky header]

Comment: This simple solution worked great for me. The only somewhat negative thing is once the header is scrolled into the data of the table it loses it's border. I'm not sure how to have the border stay.

Comment: Did you try outline instead of border?