# Fixed header table does not scroll (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

See this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q6mAY/)

I'm using the fixedheadertable plugin available [**here**](http://fixedheadertable.com)

For some reason my sample table is not scrolling, what am I doing wrong?

Initialization is done at the bottom of the javascript code:

```
$("#fixed").fixedHeaderTable();
$("#fixed").fixedHeaderTable("show");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you were missing the required CSS from the demo files, I've added them to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQL54/) and it seems to work for me now.

If you look at the [Github page](https://github.com/markmalek/Fixed-Header-Table) for the project, there's a demo folder, in there I had a look at `test.html` it included the following CSS references:

```
    <link href="../css/defaultTheme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <link href="css/myTheme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

I'm not sure specifically which styles are required for it to work as opposed to styles that are there just for cosmetic purposes as I don't have time (I just dumped all the CSS from those two files in the fiddle) but hopefully you should be able to figure that out :)

Comment: The demo was done in 960.css so I was afraid, but it looks like it works in Twitter bootstrap just fine. I'm all in!