# Table alignment when header is fixed and body scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing  an  issue in alignment of  table.I want fixed  header and scrollable  body  of  table  .I  have align  table header and  body using

```
display:table-header-group
```

I have  used following css property on table body

```
<tbody class="scrollablebody">

.scrollablebody
 {
  display: block;  //if  i  remove then  scroll bar is not  coming..i  need  scroll bar 
  overflow-y: auto;  
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

but when i  use above  css  on table body all alignment  get disturbed.
Please let me know  is there way  to  achieve this ? thanks in advance..

[jsfiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/saurabh07/7aj5fxmb/)

Comment: @user3168736 have  you checked  jsfiddle?  field of  first name get  extended similarly others..it is visible in jsfiddle..

Comment: See my answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers/25818428#25818428) for the best solution I know of. There are also tons of other answers there that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just added different id's to each table row.

HTML

```
<tr>
                <td id="name">Adam</td>
                <td id="lastname">Gil</td>
                <td id="id">0067</td>
                <td id="country">Australia</td>
                <td id="branch">Sydney</td>
                <td id="location">Sydney AU</td>
                <td id="cardno">67543</td>
                <td id="percent">50%</td>
            </tr>
```

CSS

```
#name {
    width: 13.2%;
}
#lastname {
    width: 12.9%;
}
#id {
    width: 22.8%;
}
#country {
    width: 10.5%;
}
#branch {
    width: 9.3%;
}
#location {
    width: 10.9%;
}
#cardno {
    width: 10.5%;
}
#percent {
}
```

Comment: not  working. If I add  one more  column then I have to again sets width.I am looking  for  some  generic solution.