# Does HTML5 has a built-in fixed header table?

Tags: html

Does HTML 5 has a built-in fixed header table (tbody is scrollable, but thead and tfoot are fixed)?

Comment: please see [this](http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html), as it might hold a lot of interesting info for you

Comment: Why would HTML differentiate between a table with fixed headers and one without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [this LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/T2pmq/32/) which will do as you want. (no plugins necessary)

I haven't come across/don't think there's a built in version, and so the snippet will show you an esy implementation of what you're looking to achieve.

It has a scrollable body, with both a fixed header and footer. You also have the ability to easily manipulate it using its css.

```css
html, body, #expandtable, #tablecontainer 
 {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
 }

 #tablecontainer 
 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  max-width: 900px;
 }

 #expandtable
 {
  margin: 5px 0 0 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 60%;
  border-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .breakline { clear:both;}

 .divrow
 {

 }
 
 .divcell { float:left; border: 1px solid #999; box-sizing: border-box; min-height: 30px; }
 .colname { float:left; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; box-sizing: border-box;}

 .cellwidth1 { width:10%; }
 .cellwidth2 { width:45%; }
 .cellwidth3 { width:35%; }
 .cellwidth4 { width:10%; }
```

```html
<div id="tablecontainer">

  <div id="topbar">
   <div class="colname cellwidth1">ABC</div>
   <div class="colname cellwidth2">ABC</div>
   <div class="colname cellwidth3">ABC</div>
   <div class="colname cellwidth4">ABC</div>
  </div>
  <div class="breakline"></div>
  <div id="expandtable">
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="divrow">
    <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="breakline"></div>
  <div id="topbar">
   <div class="colname cellwidth1">ABC</div>
   <div class="colname cellwidth2">ABC</div>
   <div class="colname cellwidth3">ABC</div>
   <div class="colname cellwidth4">ABC</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, You will have to implement it yourself.
You can use JS plugins that will do the job for you.
http://www.fixedheadertable.com

see also [html-table-with-fixed-headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)