# combination of border-collapse:collapse and transform:translate

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem: When I translate the header cells from a table and the table is set to border-collapse:collapse then the cells will be moved but not their borders. I created a test:

Markup:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Test 1</th>
        <th>Test 2</th>
        <th>Test 3</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td>adasdasd</td>
            <td>adasdasd</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Style:

```
table{
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #efefef;
}

th {
    background:#ccc;
    border-right: 1px #000 solid;
    transform: translate(-10px, 0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rs0h9tbu/2

If I change border-collapse to separat everything works fine.
Is it a bug, or can anybody explain that behaviour?

Comment: Hm... Did you want the left and right borders to move too? It could be argued that those borders actually belong to the `table` rather than the `th`. I think you're definitely better off with using border-collapse:separate and using, e.g. border-left and border-top on the cells and border-right and border-bottom on the table.

Comment: Whats the reason for using `transform` in tables anyhow...?

Comment: @MrLister I'am using border-right on the cell thats why I'am confused about the behaviour.

Comment: @somethinghere I need the transformation for a complex table with fixed columns and rows.

Comment: Yes, I thought you would want to use a transform on a table in this context. Just wondering at what point anyone needs transforms on _tables_, but hey, there might be a good reason. Still an interesting question, don't get me wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the behaviour of the collapsing border model. When `border-collapse` is set to `collapse`, then the cells share the border with that of the edge element which is the table. If it is set to `separate`, then the cells have their own border.

From this ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

> The border-collapse CSS property determines whether a table's borders
>   are separated or collapsed. In the separated model, adjacent cells
>   each have their own distinct borders. In the collapsed model, adjacent
>   table cells share borders.

And from this spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution

> In the collapsing border model, borders at every edge of every cell
>   may be specified by border properties on a variety of elements that
>   meet at that edge (cells, rows, row groups, columns, column groups,
>   and the table itself)

This is why when you translate the cells, only the cells move because they are not having their own borders and only sharing the borders of the edge-element (i.e. table).

If you really really need to transform and move the `th` cells, then keep the `border-collapse` as `separate` and control the borders on `td`/`th` individually.

Something like this:

```css
table {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background: #efefef;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

th,td { border: 1px solid #333; }
td { border-right: 0px; }
td:first-child { border-left: 0px; }
tbody > tr:last-child > td { border-bottom: 0px; }
th { background: #ccc; transform: translate(50px, 50px); }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Test 1</th>
            <th>Test 2</th>
            <th>Test 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td>adasdasd</td>
            <td>adasdasd</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: merci, thats what I wonted to know