# Freeze (lock) top row (heading) in MediaWiki table

Tags: mediawiki

I've looked around, and it looks like there is no way to lock the first row of a mediawiki table. By freezing, I mean, like how you [lock the top row of a spreadsheet table](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Freezing_rows_and_columns).
This seems like a very desirable feature when you're creating a table with a large number of rows, so the user doesn't have to scroll to the top to see the column name.

Does anyone know of a way to lock the header row of the table so it would just float there even when you scroll to the bottom of the long table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table with fixed headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)

Comment: No it's not. The question is specifically about Mediawiki. And my solution (see below) is different from the solution from that thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no proper solution yet for this problem in MediaWiki (and CMS in general?). It's tracked at [Bug T42763: Implement repeated/fixed/floating table headers](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T42763).

Comment: there is now! (see my solution)

Comment: @ThePhi Thanks for the update. That's only a gadget local to the English Wikipedia, which is why the MediaWiki feature request is still open. However it's a first step to see the feature request fixed in the future.

Comment: Indeed, it's a solution for the English Wikipedia, but not for my site (https://beijerterm.com).

Answer (score 5):

This is possible on the English Wikipedia with a [gadget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Gadget).

First you need to register and login. Then, go to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Preferences#mw-prefsection-gadgets

Under **Testing and development**, check **Make sure that headers of tables remain in view as long as the table is in view (requires Firefox v59 or Safari)**.

And voilà!

Comment: Do you happen to know how I might be able to implement this on my own MediaWiki wiki (which I have hosted on Namecheap)?

Comment: No idea. Maybe try to directly contact the developer of this gadget?