# want to create fixed header dynamic table with horizontal fixed column.

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Had A dynamic table with data and want to fixed header at vertical scrolling and fixed column at horizontal scrolling.

Plz Help Me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers?rq=1

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro i want to try make a table which contain fixed header, while scrolling more data inserted in table but that time header of table must be fixed.
Second things is that first column of table is fixed while horizontal scrolling.
i Fixing both issue at same time on single table.
please Suggest me.......

Comment: I think you may stop thinking in a table as `<table></table>` but in a grid system. I mean, you must use something like Twitter Bootstrap Grid System (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix boxes with css:

```
.fixed_coloumn {
   position: fixed;
}
```

Please refer to [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed)