# Sticky table header position absolute without overlap?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with `<thead>` that I want to force still on scroll while retaining formatting, alignment and structure. I tried:

```
position:absolute
```

but that skews and overlaps everything.

http://jsfiddle.net/hyo90obL/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table with fixed headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)

Answer (score 0):

```
table{
  margin-top:55px
}
.hellomylady{
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hyo90obL/)

Comment: Hi, I notice the contents of the table are no longer aligned, as well as when you scroll right, it does not stick

Comment: the best you can do is this with table...other thing is you can make a div other then table on top of it and fix it then start table after it...i think that will be the best solution

Comment: maybe with a jsfiddle?

Comment: i dont see how that helps