# How to fix on top table thead with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i am actually working on this [table](http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/434-2/) and i need to **fix on top of the table the header** `thead`  **when you scroll the table**. In my case i need to fix it via JS or jQuery and i can't edit the HTML of the table.

I tried with this script without results:

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("tablepress-10").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
    this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
});
</script>
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="tablepress-10_wrapper">
<table>...</table>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#tablepress-10_wrapper {
overflow: auto !important;
height: 400px !important;
}
```

Any ideas of what i wrote wrong? Any tips?

Thanks in advice.

PS: I am using **Wordpress**

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611581/fix-table-thead) you?

Comment: Follow this link and you will be able to solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608935/fix-table-header-thead)

Comment: @Waqas_aamer i followed exactly what they wrote, as you can see from my first post. But nothing...

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for this for a while and found most of the answers are not working or not suitable for my situation, so i wrote a simple solution with jquery.

this is the solution outline.

1. clone the table which needs to have fixed header and place the cloned copy on top of original
2. remove the table body from top table
3. remove the table header from bottom table
4. adjust the column widths. (we are remembering the original column widths)

   ```
    <head>
    <script   
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
   <script>

   function scrolify(tblAsJQueryObject, height){
   var oTbl = tblAsJQueryObject;

      // for very large tables you can remove the four lines below
      // and wrap the table with <div> in the mark-up and assign
       // height and overflow property  
   var oTblDiv = $("<div/>");
   oTblDiv.css('height', height);
   oTblDiv.css('overflow','scroll');               
   oTbl.wrap(oTblDiv);

   // save original width
   oTbl.attr("data-item-original-width", oTbl.width());
   oTbl.find('thead tr td').each(function(){
       $(this).attr("data-item-original-width",$(this).width());
   }); 
   oTbl.find('tbody tr:eq(0) td').each(function(){
       $(this).attr("data-item-original-width",$(this).width());
   });                 


   // clone the original table
   var newTbl = oTbl.clone();

   // remove table header from original table
   oTbl.find('thead tr').remove();                 
   // remove table body from new table
   newTbl.find('tbody tr').remove();   

   oTbl.parent().parent().prepend(newTbl);
   newTbl.wrap("<div/>");

   // replace ORIGINAL COLUMN width                
   newTbl.width(newTbl.attr('data-item-original-width'));
   newTbl.find('thead tr td').each(function(){
       $(this).width($(this).attr("data-item-original-width"));
   });     
   oTbl.width(oTbl.attr('data-item-original-width'));      
   oTbl.find('tbody tr:eq(0) td').each(function(){
       $(this).width($(this).attr("data-item-original-width"));
   });                 
    }

   $(document).ready(function(){
       scrolify($('#tblNeedsScrolling'), 160); // 160 is height
   });
   </script>
    </head>

   <body>
   <div style="width:300px;border:6px green solid;">
   <table border="1" width="100%" id="tblNeedsScrolling">
       <thead>
           <tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th></tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td><td>row 1, cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>row 2, cell 1</td><td>row 2, cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>row 3, cell 1</td><td>row 3, cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>row 4, cell 1</td><td>row 4, cell 2</td></tr>           
           <tr><td>row 5, cell 1</td><td>row 5, cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>row 6, cell 1</td><td>row 6, cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>row 7, cell 1</td><td>row 7, cell 2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>row 8, cell 1</td><td>row 8, cell 2</td></tr>           
       </tbody>
   </table>
   ```