# fix table header and first 2 columns in huge table angular1

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a big data table, i want to fix the header and first column and allow scroll for rest of body.

standard html table with thead and tbody

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th fix-me-on-X>ID</th>
    <th fix-me-on-X>Name</th>
    <th fix-me-on-Y>Subject 1</th>
    <th fix-me-on-Y>Subject 2</th>
    <th fix-me-on-Y>Subject 3</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <th fix-me-on-x>ID</th>
      <th fix-me-on-x>NAME</th>
      <th><input /></th>
      <th><input /></th>
      <th><input /> ..etc</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

problem is that all jquery plugins i found, either very old and not working anymore. or they break angular bindings for inputs

did anyone successfully frozen header and first column in angular1 ?

[image: Image of table]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table with fixed headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)

Comment: My advise is to not use jQuery based components for memory issues further along. I recommend is to use something like http://ui-grid.info/ which is good for large tables. For extremely large tables 100k rows use pure javascript and canvas based tables.