# HTML table with fixed headers only in Y (Scrollable in X)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a table with a fixed header **ONLY** on the Y axis (*Just like in Excel*). The problem is that it needs to be scrollable on the X axis. I found [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers) but it doesn't work for me. Here are my tests [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/nejejiq/1/edit?html,output)

I tried with

```
style="width: 400px; height: 200px; overflow: scroll;"
```

to make a test case. And with

```
position: absolute;
```

and

```
position: static;
```

To make the header static. Also tried with the answer of the other question with no positive results for me.

This is **not** a duplicate of the other question because the problems are slightly different.

I can use **CSS**, **Javascript** or *whatever* to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `thead`s position to absolute, and fix the `tr` inside it: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/x5stpv9y/

```
table {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
table thead {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
table thead tr {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;

}
```