# CSS overflow layout

Tags: css, layout, overflow

I'm trying to make a layout like native desktop application for my needs but i'm not very familiar with css.

Here an example of layout I need: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aliasdoc/fau8ogwa/)
I'm trying to use overflow like this but not work:

```
.scrollable-container {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  height: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

What I'm trying to do:
- make **.content** div fit space between **.navigation** (green) and **.footer** (yellow) div even if window is resized
- make **.scrollable-container** scrollable if content size is larger
- make table header fixed when scrolling

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put **max-height** to the `.scrollable-container` class:

```
.scrollable-container {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 190px); 
}
```

190px is the "approximate" sum of the height of header, footer, navigation and page title.

[Here is the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fau8ogwa/2/)

Comment: Hi @JuanDM, thank you for your replay, it's exactly what I want, you have an idea for making table header fixed when scrolling ??

Comment: I think this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030304/2860519) is the cleanest approach to achieve that,  take a look! hope it helps