# HTML table fixed top row without <thead>

Tags: jquery, html-table, phpexcel

I convert an Excel file into html table with the PHPExcel library.

**EDITED** output : https://jsfiddle.net/simsimzzz/d1ccqveq/15/

How can I ( JQuery ? ) fix the top row as a `<thead>`?

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="sheet0" class="sheet0 gridlines">
        <colgroup>
        <col class="col0">
        <col class="col1">
        <col class="col2">
        <col class="col3">
        </colgroup>
<tbody>
          <tr class="row0">
            <td class="column0 style3 s">Client Type</td>
            <td class="column1 style3 s">Client</td>
            <td class="column2 style3 s">N° Incident</td>
            <td class="column3 style3 s">blabla</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

PHPExcel doesn't generate `<thead></thead>`..

**EDIT** : Now I have a `<thead></thead>` , how can I fix this one and keep the width of cells according to the `<tbody>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table with fixed headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you know how to make a static `<thead>` but `<thead>` doesn't exist in your table?

Comment: yes , that's it.. i'm trying with jquery at the moment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you need create a `<thead>` then move the header row into it, from of the `<tbody>`.

Try this :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $table = $('#sheet0'); // select the table of interest
    var $thead = $('<thead/>').prependTo($table); // create <thead></thead>
    $table.find('tbody tr').eq(0).appendTo($thead); // move the header row from tbody into thead

    // Now the table is ready to have your chosen method applied to fix the position of the thead.

});
```

Comment: Super great, i have a <thead> </thead> now , can you tell me how to fixe it now ? https://jsfiddle.net/simsimzzz/d1ccqveq/15/  Thanks a lot

Comment: if I apply thead { position : fixed; } , cells dont keep the initial width according to the <tbody>

Comment: EDIT : it works great ! Solved issue ! Thanks @Roamer-1888