# Is it possible in HTML & CSS alone to align a table caption to the top AND bottom of the table?

Tags: html, css

The CSS property `caption-side` allows you to align the `<caption>` element to either the top or bottom of a table:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caption-side

How can I set the caption to appear on both the top and bottom? This could be useful for larger tables.

Ideally I would like to avoid putting a `<p>` tag or similar above the table and effectively duplicating the caption mark-up.

Comment: You can do something like changing the css class based on the scroll but that would require a little js to work.

Comment: Isn't this what headers and footers are for?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with just HTML and CSS without duplicating the caption content.

Depending on your use case, you want either the caption ([along with the table header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers) and/or footer) to remain visible when scrolling, the caption to appear at the bottom of a table large enough for the caption to disappear from the top, or the caption to always appear twice. The first two require JavaScript (and especially in the case of the former some pretty heavy DOM and layout manipulation), and the third is only possible by duplicating the caption content (with JavaScript if you prefer not to pollute your markup) *and* putting the duplicate outside of the table, because Firefox is unable to render more than one table-caption per table due to a bug.

Comment: I had a feeling that this might be the case. My requirement hadn't considered scrolling, but probably ultimately would. Right now my interest was in a replicated caption above and below the table.

Answer (score 1):

```css
table:after {
   content: attr(title);
   background-color: #333;
   color: #fff;
}

table:before {
   content: attr(title);
   background-color: #333;
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table title="O caption, my caption!">
  <tr>
   <td><a href="https://css-tricks.com/css-content/">CSS Tricks</a></td>
   <td>some text</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Not quite what you asked for, as there is now no `<caption>` element. But the caption text only appears once in the code.

Comment: I like this solution, but I don't think you can use markup within the `title` attribute.

Comment: it works if you run the code snippet. Oh - you need to format part of the caption differently than the rest? There might be a way of only formatting part of it with CSS.

Comment: CSS3 allows you to specify the format of attributes starting with, containing, or ending with a specific string http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/ (but it's not a substring-after or substring-before function)

Comment: you can format the whole `content` using CSS though.

Answer (score 0):

add in your HTML file:

```
<p id="lblCaption">YOUR CAPTION HERE</p>
```

add in your CSS file:

```
#lblCaption { position: fixed; }
```

Comment: This would duplicate the markup to achieve the desired effect - something I would like to avoid.