# Keep div at the left of the container at all time

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a calendar for practice, but I ran into a problem that I can't solve.

If you run the example, You will see the words: `Group Title` and `Test`.

When you use the scroll you will notice that `Group Title` and `Test` disappears (Of course).

Is there a way to let those stay at the left all the time.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/j4y30q1u/) because I cant post the demo in a snippet because it's over the 30000 character limit.

```
<li class="Groups_7b64f687">
    <div class="Group_7b64f687">
        <div class="Name_7b64f687" style="">Group Title</div>
        <div class="Tasks_7b64f687">
            <div class="Task_7b64f687">
                <div class="TaskName_7b64f687">Test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you already tried some similar things…

You could use `style="position:fixed; left:0;"` on your `Group_7b64f687` element:

```
<div class="Group_7b64f687" style="position:fixed; left:0;">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7huqa49/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen = Peter Hansen ?

Answer (score 0):

I can see you've used, but commented-out position:fixed.

This is part of a solution, although it doesn't work in your Fiddle for some reason that I don't have time to debug.

However, you are making a 'grid' of data with headed rows and columns. You really should be using [a table with a fixed row header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers).