# How to fixed thead or table column in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

It's very difficult to fix `thead` or table column with css. So how do I use javascript to write a universal function?

Just like this

```
$('#ele').fixedHeader();
```

or

```
var table = new Table();
table.fixed();
```

Comment: _“It's very difficult to fixed thead or table column on css”_ - No Sh*t, Sherlock. That’s why lots of articles on this topic already exist. But your “question” doesn’t sound like you did bother with either research or making an attempt of your own much. So please go read [ask] and [mcve] first, and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: please post your question in proper way with code and images.

Comment: See that `Search...` box at the top?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers