# Fixed header in HTML Table

Tags: html, css

I've tried every possible solution to get this to work, but nothing seems to be working.

I have this webpage I've created, and I have a table shown here, and I want to have my header fixed. That part I have mastered, but the thead columns dont align to the tbody columns.

I have tried assigning width to my td's manually, that didn't work either.

This is my code so far:

```css
.tableSqlContent {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}    

.tableSqlContent th, td {
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: left;
}
.tableSqlContent thead {
    background-color: #003265;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: default; 
}    

.tableSqlContent thead tr {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 37px;
}

.tableSqlContent tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {min-width: 33%;}
.tableSqlContent tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {min-width: 20%;}
.tableSqlContent tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {min-width: 20%;}
.tableSqlContent tbody tr td:nth-child(4) {min-width: 10%;}
.tableSqlContent tbody tr td:nth-child(5) {min-width: 10%;}
.tableSqlContent tbody tr td:nth-child(6) {min-width: 7%;}
.tableSqlContent thead tr th:nth-child(1) {min-width: 33%;}
.tableSqlContent thead tr th:nth-child(2) {min-width: 20%;}
.tableSqlContent thead tr th:nth-child(3) {min-width: 20%;}
.tableSqlContent thead tr th:nth-child(4) {min-width: 10%;}
.tableSqlContent thead tr th:nth-child(5) {min-width: 10%;}
.tableSqlContent thead tr th:nth-child(6) {min-width: 7%;}

.tableSqlContent tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 700px;
    overflow: auto;
    
}    

.tableSqlContent tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.tableSqlContent tbody tr:hover {
    color: #003265;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table Class="tableSqlContent">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Connectionstring</th>
                                <th>Klinik Navn</th>
                                <th>IP_Adresse</th>
                                <th>P-nummer</th>
                                <th>Systemtype</th>
                                <th>Version</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                                foreach($dbh->query($query) as $rows){
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $rows['ConnectionString']?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rows['Name']?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rows['IP_Adresse']?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rows['Ydernummer']?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rows['Systemtype']?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $rows['Version']?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table with fixed headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)

Comment: inside a thead tag use <th> instead of <td>

Comment: Do you have a public link to the site?

Comment: @Gerard As said, I have tried everything and nothing seems to be working =)

Comment: @Sfili_81 I have fixed that now =)

Comment: @Testor10 No I have not :(

Comment: @MichaelEjvindTherkildsen, It looks like it is the `display: block` and `display:inline-block` inside your `thead tr` and `body`.  When you remove that everything is aligned. Not sure if it will break something else though.

Comment: `display:inline-block; position: relative;` ?? Can you comment/remove the complete styles for `.tableSqlContent thead tr` and see if that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove some css because is in conflict:

```css
        .tableSqlContent {
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            overflow: auto;
        }    

        .tableSqlContent th, td {
            padding: 7px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .tableSqlContent thead {
            background-color: #003265;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: default; 
        }

        .tableSqlContent tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #eeeeee;
        }
        .tableSqlContent tbody tr:hover {
            color: #003265;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
        thead th {
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            top: 0px;
            z-index: 999999;
            background-color: #003265;
        }
```

```html
<table class="tableSqlContent">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Connectionstring</th>
      <th>Klinik Navn</th>
      <th>IP_Adresse</th>
      <th>P-nummer</th>
      <th>Systemtype</th>
      <th>Version</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>2222</td>
      <td>3333</td>
      <td>4444</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

hope it helps

-- added css for sticky header.

Comment: Now they are aligned.. but the fixed header is not working now =D

Comment: now it should be as you expect, added css code for sticky header.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that now all the rows are filling up my site vertically, and the scroll function from my overflow is gone, so still no fixed header function :P (I've commented out my own CSS to add yours, just to be clear on what I've done =))

Comment: Sincerly i didnt see any scroll function (if you say function i suppose a js function for scroll) but based on your code its supposed that the fixed header to be made in pure css and from the code snippet its working. Also in your code when you define .tableSqlContent tbody tr td:nth-child you have duplicated content but its ok np. may be a live version of how it looks to you can help us to help you. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpqcmLVhb7U

I've posted a video of it all, because it's based on a local network environment.

Comment: I see the video but seems the css code is different from what i posted here. sometimes you must clear cache when on localhost and sincerely if possible to have a look to the code directly may be using anydesk.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyNtoz7QM4Y

This is the site with the CSS you posted :/

Comment: Sincerely i try in my localhost and is working fine. At this point i think there is some other css code that assign to the table different style. Please check with dev tools inspector the generated table and the style it is taking.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working.

```css
.fixed_header {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed_header tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixed_header thead {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
  display: block;
}

.fixed_header th,
.fixed_header td {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table class="fixed_header">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Connection string</th>
      <th>Klinik Navn</th>
      <th>IP_Adresse</th>
      <th>P-nummer</th>
      <th>Systemtype</th>
      <th>Version</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2-0</td>
      <td>row 2-1</td>
      <td>row 2-2</td>
      <td>row 2-3</td>
      <td>row 2-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 3-0</td>
      <td>row 3-1</td>
      <td>row 3-2</td>
      <td>row 3-3</td>
      <td>row 3-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 4-0</td>
      <td>row 4-1</td>
      <td>row 4-2</td>
      <td>row 4-3</td>
      <td>row 4-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 5-0</td>
      <td>row 5-1</td>
      <td>row 5-2</td>
      <td>row 5-3</td>
      <td>row 5-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 6-0</td>
      <td>row 6-1</td>
      <td>row 6-2</td>
      <td>row 6-3</td>
      <td>row 6-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 8-0</td>
      <td>row 8-1</td>
      <td>row 8-2</td>
      <td>row 8-3</td>
      <td>row 8-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 9-0</td>
      <td>row 9-1</td>
      <td>row 9-2</td>
      <td>row 9-3</td>
      <td>row 9-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 10-0</td>
      <td>row 10-1</td>
      <td>row 10-2</td>
      <td>row 10-3</td>
      <td>row 10-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 11-0</td>
      <td>row 11-1</td>
      <td>row 11-2</td>
      <td>row 11-3</td>
      <td>row 11-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 12-0</td>
      <td>row 12-1</td>
      <td>row 12-2</td>
      <td>row 12-3</td>
      <td>row 12-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 13-0</td>
      <td>row 13-1</td>
      <td>row 13-2</td>
      <td>row 13-3</td>
      <td>row 13-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 14-0</td>
      <td>row 14-1</td>
      <td>row 14-2</td>
      <td>row 14-3</td>
      <td>row 14-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 15-0</td>
      <td>row 15-1</td>
      <td>row 15-2</td>
      <td>row 15-3</td>
      <td>row 15-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 16-0</td>
      <td>row 16-1</td>
      <td>row 16-2</td>
      <td>row 16-3</td>
      <td>row 16-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 17-0</td>
      <td>row 17-1</td>
      <td>row 17-2</td>
      <td>row 17-3</td>
      <td>row 17-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 18-0</td>
      <td>row 18-1</td>
      <td>row 18-2</td>
      <td>row 18-3</td>
      <td>row 18-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 19-0</td>
      <td>row 19-1</td>
      <td>row 19-2</td>
      <td>row 19-3</td>
      <td>row 19-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 20-0</td>
      <td>row 20-1</td>
      <td>row 20-2</td>
      <td>row 20-3</td>
      <td>row 20-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 21-0</td>
      <td>row 21-1</td>
      <td>row 21-2</td>
      <td>row 21-3</td>
      <td>row 21-4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: An explanation of how this is supposed to work would be useful man! :)