# Getting issue while using tooltip on table cell while hovering some text. and need to be table head should be fixed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Please anybody can help me out with this query.

I created a table and need tool-tip on the hover of the text in the cell , and table header should be fixed on top and scroll able.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML table with fixed headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)